# ¿Como hacer pantalla completa Formulario Windows que oculte la barra de tareas pero no la de titulo?

Tags: windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación Windows Form, y cada ventana tiene que cargar POR DEFECTO de forma maximizada y cada que esté en este estado, ocultar la barra de tareas. El problema es que he buscado y solamente he encontrado una propiedad para hacer el full screen:

```
private void MostrarPantallaCompleta()
{

 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

 this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

}
```

Es un método que mando llamar al iniciar la aplicación, pero al hacerlo me desaparece la barra de título impidiéndome cerrar la aplicación o minimizarla, siendo esto necesario en mi aplicación. Lo que quiero es que cada que la ventana esté maximizada NO desaparezca dicha barra.

Comment: En la respuesta de esta pregunta ponen un código para ocultar la barra de tareas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228090/winform-enter-fullscreen-mode

Comment: Lo intenté de esa forma y así solamente hace INVISIBLE la barra de tareas pero el formulario sigue sin ocupar ese espacio. Lo que requiero es que al maximizar el formulario este ocupe toda la pantalla y no desaparezca la barra de titulo (cerrar, minimizar, titulo, etc.,)

Comment: Hasta donde se no es posible de forma "fácil", ¿porqué no intentas simular la barra de título, un panel con los botones de cerrar y minimizar.